# C socket programming recv size

Tags: sockets

I am a newbie in socket programming(in C), maybe this question is a litter bit stupid. In C socket programming, how should I determine the size of buffer of the function recv()/read()? As in many cases, we don't know the size of data sent using send()/write(). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Beware that for stream protocols, chunk sizes in which data becomes available at the receiver do not necessarily match those at which it was sent.  Your most basic metric is the return value of the reception call.

Answer (score 0):

> how should I determine the size of buffer of the function
>   recv()/read()

Ideally one shouldn't look at these buffers and keep to the olden TCP model: keep reading bytes while bytes are available.

If you are asking this question for things like: "*how big should be the buffer into which I receive?*", the simple answer is to pick a size and just pass that. **If there's more data you can read again**.

---

Back to your original question, different stacks give you different APIs. For example on some Unixes you have things like `SIOCINQ` and `FIONREAD`. These give you the amount of data the kernel has in its receive buffer, waiting for you to copy it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really know how many bytes are expected, use a large buffer and pass a large buffer size to recv/read. These functions will return how many bytes were put into the buffer. Then you can deal with this data printing it, for example.

But keep in mind that data is often either sent in chunks of known size or sent with a message-size in the first bytes, so the receiver side is able to identify how many bytes should be read.