# c++ broken socket data

Tags: c++, sockets

### I sent data to socket

```
int index = 0, ret;
    while(size) {
        if((ret = send(sock, &buffer[index], size, 0)) <= 0)
            return (!ret) ? index : -1;
        index += ret;
        size -= ret;
    }
    cout <<"send_sock:" << buffer << endl;
```

***prints***: send_sock:HTTP/1.1 200 OK

I received data from socket

```
n = read(infd, buf, sizeof buf);        
cout << buf << endl;
```

**Prints:**~�������HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: You need to either read until you have received all the data, or handle incomplete reads. (I suspect your first `read` didn't receive anything, so you printed an uninitialized buffer.) This is covered in any introduction to TCP/IP.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923609/c-socket-programming-recv-size?rq=1